# error when the method create an object (persisted entitiy)

Tags: java, object, gwt, methods, persistence

i'm writing a web-app of a car-rental agency in java with eclipse and GWT , but i'm stuck in an error with this server method that is used by an RPC that fails, **createRentDTO**:

```
 private RentDTO createRentDTO(Rent rent) {
    return new RentDTO( createEmployeeDTO(rent.getEmployee()),
                               createClientDTO(rent.getClient()), 
                               createCarDTO(rent.getCar()), 
                               rent.getId() );
        }
```

I've noticed that if i change the *return of createRentDTO* with the following , it works:

```
     return new RentDTO(new EmployeeDTO("mike", "smith", (long) 99, "mike87","qwe123"), 
                        new ClientDTO("harry", "jones", "cl24h89"), 
                        new CarDTO("SUBARU", "supercar", (long) 25000,(long) 12), 
                        rent.getId()  
                       );
```

The problem obviously is that i can't fill the class with random values like "harry" "jones" ,but I've to take the values of the employee , client and car that i've already saved  ( i thought using the getter of rent like getEmployeeDTO .getClientDTo .getCarDTo ?) .
*How can i do it and why doesn't the first way i've tried work?*

Here some other code related to the issue:
 **Rent.class**

```
   public class Rent implements Serializable {

      Employee employee;
      Client client;
      Car car;
      long id;

      // getter and setter like:
      public Employee getEmployee() {
    return employee;
  }
      // getCar() and getClient are equal to getEmployee [...]

   }
```

*Employee, client* and *car* are all simple  classes (they are serialized  to make them savable in the database ) very similar to each others, with some attributes like name ,surname ,username, password, id or price.

I'll write only **Employee.class**

```
   public class Employee {

String name;
String surname;
@Id
Long id;
String username;
String password;

    // + getter and setter like getName() , getSurname() .....
   }
```

This is the method  **createEmployeeDTO()**  :

(createCarDTO and createClientDTO are equals...the only thing that changes are some attributes)

```
      private EmployeeDTO createEmployeeDTO(Employee employee) {
          return new EmployeeDTO(employee.getName(),
                                      employee.getSurname(), 
                                      employee.getId(),
                                      employee.getUsername(),
                                      employee.getPassword() );
      }
```

The aim  of the *rent class* is to make the user of the web application able to select which *employee* have rented a *car* to a *client*

When the RPC fails it gives a general error

> "500 The call failed on the server; see server log for details"

but the server log of jetty only says the POST method is failed and in the eclipse console there aren't errors.

thank you for the help, feel free to ask for everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your DTOs have constructors with zero arguments? Visibility is not important?
Without a zero argument constructor your call will fail.

Are your DTOs inside a shared package? If you want to use your DTOs on the server and client side, they have to be in a shared package.

Change the log level to TRACE for more informations in the server log.